# Why insert blank data into my database in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, insert

I'm newbie on ruby on rails application, from last few days I'm suffering about insert blank data into database.

This is my controller:

```
@post = Post.create(created_at: Time.now, user_id: @user.id)
```

This is my form:

```
 <%= form_for :user, url: user_path(@user), action: :create, method: :post do |f| %>

   <%= f.text_field :title %>
   <%= f.text_area :description%>
   <%= f.text_field :location%>
   <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

My model:

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

That would help me a lot, please.

Comment: have you defined parameters in params.permit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass data coming from your form to `create` method.

Update your `create` action with:

```
@post = @user.posts.create(user_params)
```

Add following method in the end of your controller:

```
private

# For strong parameters
def user_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :location)
end
```

---

**Don't ignore** that you need to understand following:

1. You don't need to pass `created_at` value manually. Let framework handle this for you.
2. `@user.posts.create` means, you are creating `posts` for `@user`. `@user.posts.create` will auto-populate your `user_id` column.
3. You should use [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) for security reasons.

Further suggested reading: [Rails Official Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).